# window.print() is not printing the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page 
[image: screenShot]

I want to print this page.  On print button i am using something like this

```
<input id="print" type="submit" onclick="window.print();" />
```

But the problem is it is not printing the whole page. Like it only print that is currently in the view. When i click on the print button then till `Email:tahir@7-cs.com` page print. It does not print the text below the scrollbar.

[image: textBelowScrollbar]

How can i print the whole text. Like suppose i have a very big page and i am using tabs to accommodate my page. And when click on print button, then i want to include the whole page including tabs. How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: The last time I dealt with this issue was back in IE6 (so my advice might be out of date), but back then any iframes or other elements with overflow hidden content would print only what was visible on screen - which kind of makes sense if you think about what would happen if you had side-by-side iframes with different length content. We got around it by having our print button open a child window with a print-preview version of the current page that replaced all iframes with divs and then calling `window.print()` on the preview window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should use a separate css file for printing the page or use css3 media queries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

using percentage values its the best option when you create a css print file.

```
body, html, #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

or in your main css file:

```
@media print {
      body, html, #wrapper {
          width: 100%;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , you mean i will have to make a css file print.css. And the contents that i don't want to include in print, give ids to them and then set their display none. And after including this declaration `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>` on my page, when i click on print button then browser use this print.css file to print the page. Is it?

Comment: @Basit, yes browsers use css print stylesheets for printing the page. this way you have complete control over styles of elements.

Comment: I have a css file that is including on my page. I added these lines into my file `@media print {body, html{width: 100%;}}`. I did nothing on my page. What i understand it means print whatever in the body oh the html document? Is it? But it is still not printing the whole body, means all elements that is inside <body>..</body>

Comment: @Basit when you set the 100% to body, make sure you set percentage values to other elements, like #sidebar 40% using large pixel values overflow the design.

Comment: HHmm i did one more thing. I added these lines in the css `#top, #bottom {display: none;}`. It is working. Mean file is including. What if i remove the 'width: 100%' form the css? Thanks

Comment: @Basit not using 'width: 100%' is not recommended, when you set the width to 100% you can style other elements according to the wrapper or body, for example setting sidebar width to `30%` means `30%` of the width of body or #wrapper.

Comment: Hmm. my whole content that i want to print is in the div content. So you are basically saying that i use some thing like `{body, html, #content{width: 100%}}` or use `{body, html{width:100%}}` and apply style on my div like `<div id="content" style="width: 30%" />`. Thanks

Comment: @Basit yes, you can change the values to see what makes you more satisfied with the results. you are welcome :)

Comment: Now i tried this `@media print {body, html{width: 100%;height: 100%;} #top, #bottom {display: none;}}`.  And on my div i used this `<div id="content" style="width: 50%; height:100% " >..</div>`, But the result is same. Not printing the whole document. What i am doing wrong? :(

Comment: its better to not using inline styles for print, you are using media queries, make sure that your browser supports media queries and also check that there is no pixel value that has been set for inner elements.

Comment: I think my browser is supporting media queries because if it doesn't then the `#top, #bottom{display: none}` doesn't work. HHmm yes i am using something like this `<div id="content" style="width: 50%; height:100% "><img  style="height: 153px" /><div style="margin-top: 135px; margin-left:200px" /></div>`. Means i am using inline styling for all my elements that are in the content div and also using pixel like 135px and so on...... So it means now i will have to remove all inline styling from my elements. And i can't use pixle on my elements instead i will have to use % in the css. Am i right?

Comment: @Basit yes, use percentage as it makes you sure that all elements will be printed as you want in different browsers and monitors.

Comment: HHmm thanks one thing more. Suppose i have a page. I use style in my css like `html,body{width:100%, height:100%}`. I have divs say <div id="div1" ><input id="name" type="text" /></div><div id="div2" ><input id="submit" type="submit" /></div> and so on. Now if i set my div1 style in my css file like `#div1{width:30%; height 50%;}`. So it means i am saying that set div1 style 30% of the body. Like if 100% of body width is suppose 1000px on the monitor then it means div1 width become 300px. Am i right?

Comment: I think i found the problem. You guided me really well and i learned today that what is @media about :). Actually i have internal scrollbar because of which i am having this issue. <link>http://jsfiddle.net/nAFSN/ .  You will see that i am using contents inside div but with scrollbars. What i was trying to do is to print the contents of this div. I want that all the contents in this get print, but i think it is not possible? What do you say?

Comment: i glad that could help you, you can add some styles to your print section to override scrollbars http://jsfiddle.net/nAFSN/1/

Comment: awsome. Simply genius :). Thanks a lot man;). Only one thing remain. When i print the document that at the very top i get link of the page and at the very bottom on the right side i get date. Is it normal? Like on my page there is no date. It get link of the address bar. Can i remove it also or it is normal? Thanks

Comment: you are welcome man, that data is produced by the browser, you can deselect them within browser print config section, but you cannot force other browsers to not use them, as it is a native functionality of them.

Comment: Where can i find this browser print config section? like i am using firefox.

Comment: you can call it by `command + p` on mac, and `control + p`  on windows.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooo much:). Now everything is fine.Thanks a lot man. tc ;)

Answer (score 3):

use

```css
  body,html { margin-top:0%;
   display:block;
   height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 3):

### using this CSS

```
@media print{ 
    body, html, #page-container, .scrollable-page, .ps, .panel {
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS print stylesheets, have a look at google for [some examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+print+stylesheet).

On why it actually doesn't print the whole page, I assume you're missing a setting on your print dialog that states how the printing will be done.