# How to print specific div content using jquery with out using window.print() method

Tags: jquery

I want to print the entire div content using jquery.

Currently I am using `window.print()` method. But it displays only some content in print page and some content missing.

I want to print entire  data in my print page.

Comment: can you show your code.

Comment: <!--  <script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#printButton").click(function () {
  
  window.print();
  
 });
 
});
</script>

Comment: Your css might have "@media" styles for print mode preventing some of your content to display correctly. See more info about "@media" here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: suppose i want to print 1000 line of data in my print page .but using method window.print() it  prints 10 lines of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a separate css file for printing the page or a css3 media queries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

**css file:**

```
body, html, #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**or main css file:**

```
@media print {
      body, html, #wrapper {
          width: 100%;
      }
}
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845621/window-print-is-not-printing-the-whole-page)

Comment: using this also  am getting same output.

Comment: @KundrapuAppalanaidu Which one did you try?

Comment: css file and main css file

Comment: @KundrapuAppalanaidu Did you add `media="print"` in `link`?